# Angular (click) function only working properly in macOS

Tags: angular

Im using a select-tag in my frontend to retrieve movies within a genre from the database. It's done through angular 4 and mongodb. The frontend looks like this:

```
<select name="select" id="selectGenre" (click)="clearSearch()" (change)="getGenres()" [(ngModel)]="wantGenre">
        <option value="null" disabled="true" [selected]="true">Select genre: </option>
        <option name="horror" value="Horror">Horror</option>
        <option name="romance" value="Romance">Romance</option>
        ...
</select>
```

It is not a perfect functionality, but the clearSearch() receives ALL the movies in the database, then getGenres() gets all the movies within the given genre. We're doing it this way to easily change between the genres.

The problem is: This functionality works perfect in macOS. We get the movies within the given genre every time. But when we try it with a linux or windows(10)-computer, it runs clearSearch() twice, one time before getGenres() and one after getGenres(). I dont understand why, anyone got any experience with issues like this?

Answer (score 0):

`clearSearch()` runs twice because it's attached to the `click` event. One time when you click on the `select` element to show de dropdown, and one time when you click to choose de value of the Genre (Horror/Romance).

You should run `clearSearch()` one time in your `ngOnInit()` function in your component to load the data, not in the view.

View:

```
    <select name="select" id="selectGenre" (change)="getGenres()" [(ngModel)]="wantGenre">
      <option value="null" disabled="true" [selected]="true">Select genre: </option>
      <option name="horror" value="Horror">Horror</option>
      <option name="romance" value="Romance">Romance</option>
      ...
    </select>
```

Component:

```
import { OnInit } from '@angular/core';
...
@Component({...})
export class Movies implements OnInit {
constructor(...)
ngOnInit() {
  clearSearch();
}

clearSearch() {
  //Code that retrive all movies list from server
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering! The problem is that we need the "clearSearch()"-function in the (click) because we need clearSearch() to happen before getGenres() every time.. getGenres will work the first time, but the second time it will only search through the new list with movies. The clearSearch() resets and then we search through the whole list with movies.

Comment: I don't really understand then! :D the `clearSearch()` resets the search results or some search options? And also, the application is supposed to run on a browser, why is it working on macOs? BTW, the `options` should not have a `name` attribute, the `select` should.

Comment: Before you answer this comment, I know the code sucks, but we are in a time hurry so cant change the whole system now :P
getGenre() search through a list called this.movies, but when you use getGenre()(with lets say "horror") this.movies will consist of all movies with "horror" as genre. When you use getGenre() again, it will search within this.movies as usual, but it only consists of horror-movies now. Therefore, with clearSearch(), this.movies becomes every movie in the database.

Sorry if this was explained badly :p